# C# Framework Version - Working with Multiple frameworks

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an app using **.Net Core (1.01)** which works well and all fine. But there is no PayPal SDK for .net core.

To get around this issue I thought of loading **.net 4.6.1** into my project so I could use this SDK from there, while the rest of my project continued on using .net core.

This kind of works, my project builds but I get thousands of errors referencing - Project: "ProjectName..NET Framework 4.6.1"

Below is a copy of my project.json

```
{
  "userSecretsId": "xxxxx",

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.2.281",
        "ChilkatDnCore": "9.5.0.59",
        "CsvHelper": "2.16.3",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
          "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
          "type": "build"
        },
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": {
          "version": "1.0.1",
          "type": "build"
        },
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
          "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
          "type": "build"
        },
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "version": "1.0.1",
          "type": "platform"
        },
        "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
        "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
          "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
          "type": "build"
        },
        "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
          "type": "build",
          "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
        }
      },
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    },
    "net461": {
      "imports": [
      ],
      "dependencies": {
        "PayPal": "1.7.4"
      }
    }
  },


  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  }
}
```

I have never attempted to do a cross framework project. So any assistance would be appreciated.

Caz

**-- UPDATE --**

So I moved my dependency list out of the framework specific list and only one had an error with .net 4.6 so I moved that back into the core dependency list and everything seems to build well without errors.

But there is now a new error. Creating a new class and add the PayPal API `using PayPal.Api` I get the error **"Namespace PayPal could not be found"**

The odd this is the intellisense knows about it, when I start adding it I get a warning **".net 4.6 - available -- .net core - unavailable"**, so obviously its there, I just need to somehow tell it to use the 4.6 framework for that using statement...

Comment: Your best bet would probably be to have a separate service layer that you can call through HangFire or an API that will house the PayPal code still in .NET 4.6.1 while the rest of your code is in Core. That, or have it all in 4.6.1.